# mysql min where statement

Tags: mysql, sql, select, min

so we have the mysql MIN() function for getting the minimum in a table...but what if I want to get a MIN() based on a criteria

so something like MIN(age) WHERE height < 170

in which the aim is to get the minimum age of ONLY people whose height is < 170...so say sam is the youngest of those with height < 170, but pam is younger than sam but have height > 170, then the query should return sam instead of pam...

how would I compose such query?

Comment: You mean the query will return 23 (Sam's age), right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say you want the "minimum age of ONLY people whose height is < 170"

```
SELECT MIN(age)
FROM YourTable
WHERE height < 170
```

Will in fact work as you require then!

`WHERE` limits row pre aggregation, `HAVING` can be used to filter on the results of aggregations.

Comment: You mean `select name from yourtable where height < 170 having min(age)` otherwise "Pam" will still not show up :-)

Comment: @Johan - No, I was very careful to quote the phrase in the OP's question that my answer pertains to. If they **do** want the name as well they should just use `WHERE`, `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` to get the first row.